# Efficiently joining text in nested lists

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Suppose I have a text represented as a collection of lines of words. I want to join words in a line with a space, and join lines with a newline:

```
class Word {
  String value;
}

public static String toString(List <List <Word>> lines) {
    return lines.stream().map(
            l -> l.stream().map(w -> w.value).collect(Collectors.joining(" "))
    ).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
}
```

This works fine, but I end up creating an intermediate String object for each line. Is there a nice concise way of doing the same without the overhead?

Comment: Can you collect into a intermediate StringBuilder and then map the construction function and the collection to string? (sorry don't remember java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
public static String toString(List<List<Word>> lines) {
    return lines.stream()
        .map(l -> l.stream()
                   .map(w -> w.value)
                   .collect(() -> new StringJoiner(" "),
                            StringJoiner::add,
                            StringJoiner::merge))
        .collect(() -> new StringJoiner("\n"),
                       StringJoiner::merge,
                       StringJoiner::merge).toString();
}
```

The inner `collect` basically does what `Collectors.joining(" ")` does, but omits the final `StringJoiner.toString()` step.

Then, the outer `collect` differs from an ordinary `Collectors.joining("\n")` in that it accepts `StringJoiner` as an input and combines them using `merge`. This relies on [a documented behavior](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html#merge-java.util.StringJoiner-):

> If the other `StringJoiner` is using a different delimiter, then elements from the other `StringJoiner` are concatenated with that delimiter and the result is appended to this `StringJoiner` as a single element.

This is done internally on the `StringBuilder`/character data level without creating a `String` instance while retaining the intended semantic.

Answer (score 5):

```
 String s = List.of(
            List.of(new Word("a"), new Word("b")),
            List.of(new Word("c"), new Word("d")),
            List.of(new Word("e"), new Word("f")))
            .stream()
            .collect(Collector.of(
                    () -> new StringJoiner(""),
                    (sj, list) -> {
                        list.forEach(x -> sj.add(x.getValue()).add(" "));
                        sj.add("\n");
                    },
                    StringJoiner::merge,
                    StringJoiner::toString));
```

**EDIT**

I can thing of this, but can't tell if you would agree for the extra verbosity vs creating that String:

```
.stream()
.collect(Collector.of(
          () -> new StringJoiner(""),
          (sj, list) -> {
              int i;
              for (i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; ++i) {
                 sj.add(list.get(i).getValue()).add(" ");
              }
              sj.add(list.get(i).getValue());
              sj.add("\n");
          },
          StringJoiner::merge,
          x -> {
              String ss = x.toString();
              return ss.substring(0, ss.length() - 1);
          }));
```

Comment: just meant to answer as well : 
https://www.mscharhag.com/java/java-8-string-join

Comment: This is good, but it leaves a space after each line, and a newline after the last line. So it's not quite the same functionality.

Comment: The level, you’re operating on, drops any benefit of the `StringJoiner` and the code would be almost the same when using `StringBuilder` directly. And the final `substring` operation kills the entire benefit of it, as it implies copying the whole character contents from an intermediate `String` instance to another. When using `StringBuilder` directly, you could avoid that using `sb.setLength(sb.length()-1)` before `toString()`. But, of course, you have to add handling of empty list. And with the loop within the collector you’re not doing much of a Stream operating, actually.